# Before every ajax request using jQuery, I want to do sth

Tags: javascript, jquery

means, do sth, then request using jQuery, like a hooker. How can i do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.ajaxSetup()` for this

[Full documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/)

For example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
       //do something, like show 'Requesting....'
    }
});
```